# Button is closing WindowsForm automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application that checks for pending changes whenever the user hits the cancel button. If there are pending changes, I prompt the user to see if they are sure they wish to cancel. If they do, I close the form. If not, I just return. However, the form is closing anyways. After some debugging, I realized it was because this particular button is set to the form's [`CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx), so clicking it caused the form to close. To verify, I removed the `CancelButton` property, but the behavior persisted.

How can I prevent this automatic closing? Here is my event handler code:

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = DialogResult.Yes;

    if (changesMade)
    {
        dr = MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Are you sure you wish to disregard the changes made?", "Changes Made", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Close();
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

In the above code, the form should only close if there are no changes made, or if the user chose to disregard them. I made changes, and clicked 'No' to the DialogBox, but the form still closed. With and without the button set as the form's CancelButton.

Comment: I'd recommend doing your check in the `FormClosing `event rather than the `ButtonClick`. Then just set `e.Cancel` accordingly. That way, whatever closes your form (Be it File -> Exit, the X button in the top right, etc) will always prompt for unsaved changes.

Comment: Did you debug properly, using breakpoints and F10? The cause for the misbehavior should be easy to find.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Yes, though I didn't try to step into anything other than this method.

Comment: So, the form closes although close() isn't called? If so, then comment out the whole code in that function and check again. If still closing, you need to look somewhere else.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss it does. I will look elsewher,e and I will try sab's solution as well as the posted answer.

Comment: You're sure, you removed the 'cancelbutton'? You could remove the button completely and create a new one. Further diagnosis is difficult as we can't see your code.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I am positive, and I even did a rebuild of the entire solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, this is what I do for an internal tool I wrote recently:

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !PromptUnsavedChanges();
}

private bool PromptUnsavedChanges()
{
    if (HasFormChanged()) //checks if form is different from the DB
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("You have unsaved changes. Would you like to save them?", "Unsaved Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            tsmiSave_Click(null, null); // Saves the data
        else if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
            return false; // Cancel the closure of the form, but don't save either
    }

    return true; // Close the form
}
```

The logic could probably cleaned up from a readability point of view, now that I'm looking at it months later. But it certainly works.

With this you simply just call `this.Close();` in your button click event. Then that event is what handles the prompting and decides if it should actually close or not.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I am going with this solution as I find it more readable.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'd probably change it to include `HasFormChanged` in the actual closing event before calling the prompt, and maybe invert the return values to remove the `!` but whatever.

Comment: I just changed my method to `IgnoreChanges()` which returns, intuitively, yes to cancel and no otherwise. So in FormClosing I read `e.Cancel = !IgnoreChanges()`. Makes sense to me! Hopefully future me who debugs this thinks so too.

Comment: Beware, FormClosing happens for various reasons. Check the CloseReason in the FormClosingEventArgs.

Comment: @Steve Good to know, I was not aware of that. [Link to the CloseReason enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Just set the property DialogResult of the form to the enum DialogResult.None

```
....
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Close();
}
else
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

or simply:

```
if (dr != DialogResult.Yes)
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
```

The form closes automatically because the property DialogResult of the button is not set to DialogResult.None in the Forms Designer. In this scenario, the WinForms engine takes that value and assign it to the DialogResult property of the whole form causing it to automatically close. This is usually used in the calling code of the form to distinguish between a Confirm and a Cancel button

In the example below suppose that on the frmCustomers there are two buttons, one with the DialogResult property set to DialogResult.OK and another set to DialogResult.Cancel. Now if the user hits the OK button you know, in the calling code what to do with the inputs for your new customer

```
using(frmCustomers f = new frmCustomers())
{
    if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       // Execute code to save a customer
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I am going with the FormClosing solution though, as I think it keeps things more readable.